# Creating a Module Level Main Menu Replacement

Tags: 7, theming, routes, hooks

I am looking to create a module (not theme) that replaces/augments the main menu in Drupal 7.

I've got a CSS driven menu (MegaMenu style). It's generic and I want to reuse it across projects/themes... thus my desire for a module.

(*NOTE: I'll also be taking this to WordPress plugin, so maintaining reusable core code is a high priority. Drupal or WordPress themes, can respin my basic styles for visual integration.*)

Creating a module to inject my CSS was easy enough, then I tested with **Bartik** which doesn't expand child menu items.

I believe I should be overriding theme calls to **links__system_main_menu**.

Everything I've found (specific enough to be useful) resolves around **template.php** and THEMENAME_links__system_MENU_NAME.

I'm not getting anything when I try replacing THEMENAME with MODULENAME (i.e. MODULENAME_links__system_main_menu).

I've also looked at **hook_menu** and **hook_menu_alter**, but I'm just not seeing a reliable or elegant way to do this.

The most concise example of what I'm looking to do (in a theme-based approach) is: [Turn your main menu into a Superfish menu](http://othermachines.com/blog/drupal-turn-main-menu-into-superfish-menu)

**TLDR: How can I ensure that Main Menu is written out in expanded tree mode without relying on theme level code?**

I realize there will likely be a need to override/prune any existing Main Menu theme styles.

Comment: From the theme level, using **menu_tree_all_data()**, **menu_tree_output()** and **drupal_render()** works... i.e. (one-liner: `print drupal_render(menu_tree_output(menu_tree_all_data('main-menu')));` ) Just make sure to break things out and use a variable to pass to menu_tree_output() which appears to be expecting a reference... despite what the API says.

Comment: I think @floatingpointmatt your comment above has the best approach if it must be in a module, but I would use `links__system_main_menu` in a template.php, could you consider using a base theme rather than a module?  Otherwise you're going to be replicating a lot of core functionality in a module to generate the menu, looking at the menu_block module will give you an idea of the complexity of the task: https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block

Comment: Thanks @bloke_zero! I think you're probably right. I was hoping for something a little cleaner, but everything I've seen uses block level menus (as opposed to the base Bartik inclusion), so that's another road to go down. I also ran across [TB Mega Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/tb_megamenu) as a fallback (and a good one at that). I just wanted something I could take cross platform (and explain easily to clients...). Not defeated, but reconsidering... Thanks again!

Comment: No problem - the theme/module divide has some weird edge cases that are tricky in practice - especially menus - I came up against the exact same problem with bootstrap compliant menus which I would have liked to put in a module for re-use across sites but settled for a base-theme style approach using `links__system_main_menu`.  Good luck!